# How to use two user accounts in flutter

Tags: flutter, macos

I am on macOS developing flutter apps. I have 2 user accounts. I have put both users in one group named 'sharedusers'.
Flutter tools and the flutter projects are in the /Users/Shared folder.
So, the folder have 'user1:sharedusers' permissions.

But when I use user2 and edit a file in VS code and run 'Run without debugging' I got an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:assembleDebug'.
> Could not copy file '/Users/Shared/flutter/05_Interactivity/expense_tracker/build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk' to '/Users/Shared/flutter/05_Interactivity/expense_tracker/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk'.
   > Could not set file mode 777 on '/Users/Shared/flutter/05_Interactivity/expense_tracker/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk'.
```

I have set permissions with:
sudo chmod -R g+wrx 05_Interactivity

I also have set permissions in finder. But I always got this error.
The only think that works is using chown and set it to the current logged in user like:
sudo chown -R user1:sharedusers or
sudo chown -R user2:sharedusers

Why does it not work with the group?
Is there a restriction in flutter?